Defeating a homeland that can't be invaded
So there's a country in my world the size of North America. It's an aggressive, imperialist nation. Eventually, it gets its comeuppance and is soundly beaten by a coalition of nations.
There's just one problem.
Nobody can occupy the nation's homeland. This isn't 'it's too far' or 'too rugged', no, the nation's homeland is inhospitable to human life. A combination of a deadly climate, toxins in the soil and water, and lack of food of any sorts ensures no normal human can survive for long. This nation was like this before the war (their inhabitants have long since ceased being humans).
So the question is: how do you even defeat a nation like this if you can't even put your troops into their territory?
Some extra rules:

Being within the country for more than 2 hours means a painful death
The technology level is 2000 CE level
Did I mention this nation's homeland looks terrifying? Like something out of Hell. Or worse.

Note: Defeat means 'the country is weakened so much it can't achieve its goals by force'

This seems like a question about how a fight would play out. These questions aren't about facts of your world but events that transpire within your, already built, world. We are not here to write your story for you. The specific circumstances you choose to have play out have far more influence on the outcome than anything related to the world itself.

Before you get too many answers, please add as rule #4 specifically what you mean by "defeat." @L.Dutch makes a good point in a comment to his answer - if "defeat" means "stop the enemy's ability to make war forever" then nuking the snot out of the country (nuclear winter be damned!) is a pretty obvious solution. In fact, anything delivered ballistically would work (e.g., poison). Simplistically, the only time troops matter is if you want someone in the target nation to survive (civilians... kittens...).

Send in some Doomguys. These kids are well-known to have survived in Hell or worse environments.

Do they have nukes and a nuclear triad? If so there's probably no way of defeating them militarily. Are they (potentially) self-sufficient? If so, there's probably no way of defeating them by siege/starvation/economic sanctions.

@JBH Nuking an area the size of North America is a non-trivial task even before you get into the problems of nuclear winter for yourself.

Wasn't the USA defeated in several wars in the 20th century, without a single enemy soldier setting foot inside the country? A nation can lose a war without being occupied, if it loses the will to fight, if it gets too expensive to justify further involvement, if it finds that it's not longer worth fighting it.

@Mary That's just another reason for asking the OP to define the word "defeat." O'course... that requires the OP to participate in this process...


how do you even defeat a nation like this if you can't even put your troops into their territory?

Japan in WWII was defeated without a single soldier setting foot on its homeland. How? Well, the history is known: faced with the prospect of being hammered with nukes and with already non existing perspectives on flipping the table, a surrender was preferred.
It's the same old story of besieging a castle in ancient times, just on a larger scale: if you can't take them by force, take them by hunger.
In your case:

you need to be able to cut off all the influx of resources to the country.
the country must be poor in vital resources on its own.
you must have a way of dealing big blows with limited human costs on your side: nobody likes home funerals.

Then you will be able to bring the country to its knees.

Post WW2 reconstruction though defeats this as an example.

@TheDemonLord OP asked about defeating, not about occupying

The real defeat of Japan was not just the surrender in Tokyo Bay, it was occupation by allied forces and reforms and demilitarization that happened betwen 1945-1952. As has been shown multiple time in recent years - the US can easily win any military conflict, but without the taking and holding of land and societal reforms - the Enemy is not Defeated (See Iraq, Afghanistan etc.)

Don't ignore that the Soviet Union which had signed a neutrality agreement with Japan invaded Japan held territory (Manchuria) two days after the bombing of Hiroshima. Japan was faced with a two front war all of a sudden. For Japan, the war radically changed at that moment.

@TheDemonLord Look at those wars from the other side. America was defeated in Afghanistan and Vietnam without being invaded and occupied. Fundamentally, defeat is when a side gives up, and different sides have different stakes and tolerances for losses.

America was defeated in Afghanistan -- @jb6330 note that the ONLY goal was to prevent more mass terrorism from being launched from Afghan soil.  The goal seems to have been met, no?  Granted we can't be sure there will be no more terrorism forever.  But there hasn't been so far, and I think the Taliban can picture losing control of their territory for another generation should they allow or commit some, so they now have a vested interest in avoiding such terrorists in the future.

@SwissFrank Putting my choice of example aside, my point is that occupation and reformation is not a prerequisite for defeat. Defeat is determined when a side gives up, and not every country will fight for every cause to the bitter end.
I'm more or less trying to say that there does exist an answer to OP's question.

Nuke it, bomb it, starve it, rob it!
Win by PR (Vietnam it)!
Climate change it: dry it, flood it!
Economics: crash stock market!

Media - it beat the Irish!
Thousand years they fought the English!
Now they give away their old wish
TV beat 'em, ain't that some shit.

Hack it, doxx it, disinform it!
Fund some locals: Civil War it!
Coastal cities? Shell it, shell it!
Got corruption? Easy: bribe it!

Nuke it, bomb it, starve it, rob it!
Nuke it, bomb it, starve it, rob it!
Nuke it, bomb it, starve it, rob it!
Nuke it, bomb it, starve it, rob it!
(Instrumental outtro.)

This is a fun answer, is it a reference?

@DanielB not that I'm aware of!

I read this to the tune of Daft Punk's "Technologic" -- I assume that was intentional?

@ChrisTaylor unintentional, but now that you mention it, I bet that it was subconsciously present!

LOL, I heard Daft Punk too, but I thought it was "Harder, Better, Faster, Stronger"

Can someone remind me in a few hours so I can put this into an AI music generator (or someone else do it)?

Defeating doesn't mean invading. It means that one side of the conflict is relatively weakened so much that it stops trying to achieve its goals by force. Being soundly defeated simply means that you don't really have a choice in the matter; it would have been pointless to try to achieve your goals by force even if you did decide to do it.
So you may be looking at an aftermath of something like the Bay of Pigs invasion. There the attacking nation (the USA) was repelled, and subsequent attacks became pointless as a result. It was not necessary for the USA to be invaded, or to cease being a superpower, or even to suffer significant losses on Cuban soil; all it took was Cuba responding by getting friendly with the USSR. All of a sudden a second attack on Cuba would have meant going to war with a peer nuclear power (which very nearly happened just a year and a half later during the Cuban Missile Crisis). Just shifting the relative balance between USA and Cuba was sufficient.

Air power, missiles and drones.
Since the country has been "soundly beaten", I assume its military capabilities are severely degraded and the coalition has air power. I also assume that you don't want to go full nuclear winter (otherwise this wouldn't be a question). The next phase is likely to look like Desert Storm or Yugoslavia with extra B-2s. The coalition will bomb SAM and radar sites, airfields, communications and energy infrastructure, military command points, government buildings, factories, bridges and railroads. Given that the inhabitants have "long since ceased being humans", they'll be viewed as subhumans and civilian casualties will be ignored or even encouraged. Chemical and even biological weapons may be considered. Once air defenses are sufficiently destroyed, Predator drones or equivalent will begin to be used to patrol the territory and blow up any vehicle that moves - civilian or military. You can keep this up for as long as you want. The economy comes to a complete standstill, society collapses. What's left of the military probably turns into rival groups fighting among themselves. You can't occupy the territory (and don't want to), but you've guaranteed that it won't be a threat to anybody for a very long time.
Edit: if/when a power struggle breaks out, you can sell weapons to different factions, making profits and maintaining political instability to hinder the country rebuilding.

From my comment - I do not consider merely nuking a country to be defeating them.
To use a topical example - the current Isreal conflict, there is a huge disparity in firepower and casualties - but has Hamas been defeated? Even if they nuked part of Palestine and Hamas asked for a cease-fire - that is not defeating them.
No, Defeating an Enemy means that you take away the capability for them to fight, which means you need boots on the ground.
However - you put your tech level at the 2000s - we have had NBC (Nuclear,
Biological and Chemical) suits and MBTs and other kit since the 1950s - and I am allowed to presume that if this was the main threat - that extra emphasis would be placed on this sort of technology.
Therefore - Frame Challenge, with your tech level, we have the ability to hermetically seal a soldier in a protective suit for at least 50 years at this point - as such, the notion that the soldiers would not be issued protective gear to be able to fight in this hostile environment is unreasonable
To expand on this - even if we assume that the environment is so hostile as to damage these suits, we would still have APCs, MBTs and other such protected equipment that would allow infantry units to move to an area, disembark for a period of time - then return and decontaminate. Especially if this country is the existential threat you paint it as, we would find a solution here.
However, there is one other option...
To Defeat an Enemy - you need to either take away their will to fight or their means to fight - assuming they have an unbreakable will and that they can manufacture food and material with their own natural resources (and a North American-esque country has enough Mineral wealth to do this) - there is one other solution... A Final Solution if you will..
Down to the last Man, Woman and Child
It is dirty, it is brutal and it is every bit definitionally a Genocide - but that is the one sure-fire way to Defeat an Enemy whose land you cannot take and hold - by killing all of them.

Since this nation is explicitly non-human, genocide is probably very much on the table. You don't need to kill all of them - just enough of them in the right places that society breaks down and they start killing each other. It may not be a permanent solution - since there's apparently no competition for the territory, eventually someone will take power and rebuild, but you'll set them so far back that they won't be a serious threat for a very long time (and you can help by fueling political instability).

Disagree.  Nuking Gaza would not defeat Hamas.  But Hamas is dependent on outside resources.  Remove those resources and they would quickly fall.  You drop your bomb on Tehran and announce that you'll do the same thing to the capital of any country that supplies Hamas.

Only if they are dependent on the rest of the world.
You mention lack of food.  Is that a lack for humans, or its no-longer human inhabitants?  If its inhabitants need your food, you can starve them out.  But if they are not dependent on you -- and so dependent they can not work out how to become independent -- they are basically unconquerable.
One of the reasons that Great Britain did not declare war on the United States over the Trent Affair was that the War Office realized that such a war would basically hand the US Canada on a platter.  And that's with only part of North America, and the continent is human-habitable.

Subvert the Enemy:
So humans can't go into this region. Fine. But the enemy was once human, and their attitudes are likely somewhat human. If they are human-like, then they are susceptible to all the desires of humans.
Bribes:
Get members of their species to do your bidding. Even evil, nasty species are still vulnerable to greed and internal conflicts. Interfere with their government. Support factions against each other. Bribe officials to give you information about where to bomb, commit sabotage and tell you about their vulnerabilities.
Mercenaries:
Hire mercenaries. Unless they have a very strong internal system of loyalties, you can hire individuals to do fighting for you. With modern weapons, you can have every merc driving a tank or flying a bomber to increase effective strength.
Break the Will to Fight:
Attrition:
Wear out the enemy homeland. Promise anyone who leaves it basic security. Then bomb it if pilots can go over. Fire rockets and missiles (even big cannons) to blast anything worth having. Repeat. Repeat. I'm assuming the locals are extremely resistant to poisons and plagues, but if not spray and spread like crazy. This is scorched Earth, so enemy civilians are targets. Destroy everything man-made.
Know their Ecosystem:
Hell has no resources, no food or plants, no animals. No life. An empire can't exist without basic resources, or there IS no war and the problem is solved.
So there must be a new ecosystem that provides the basic needs of the modified life. Whatever these things are, study them and then learn how to disrupt them. Those burning plains may actually be a huge photosynthetic mat that produces methane as a waste product and ignites it to make their environment hotter - use cloud seeding to cause deadly cooling rains.
Those demonic monsters roaming the wastes may be intelligent, or they may reproduce rapidly when fed and start eating your enemy. Piling up meat on the border could be catastrophic.
Or something as humble as a weed, spread on "farm" land could starve out the enemy or make the terrain toxic for them as the weeds leech essential toxins from the environment.

Biological Warfare
It is unlikely that these plants/animals/diseases would be viable in such a toxic climate. But with 2000 technology some experimental crossbreeding could get you far as long as you don't let ethics stop you.
Introduce drugs
Find some of the more corruptible members of the enemy, and give them method/seeds to grow plants that can be refined into opiates. That should keep a part of the population busy. May even cause a few civil wars.
Introduce invasive species.
Setting free some species that would manage to not only survive, but thrive better than the ones that are already there could seriously mess up their ecosystem. Devastating -for example- farming, or certain wildlife they might hunt/be eaten by. The best species would have no positive use. Maybe do a fly-over spreading tumbleweed seeds? Bring in some cane toads? Desert locusts?
This won't show effect in the first year, but a well placed invasion should have a lasting effect. Even if just tying up people to try to prevent the invasive species from spreading.
Introduce diseases
Find some disease that can transfer to your enemies -or their livestock- and spread it around. Preferably either one that can stay hidden for a short time, or one that is nearly impossible to treat. One that does not spread to humans. Some sort of anthrax for their species? Rabies? Or some other disease.
All of these options will slow down your enemy from building up another attack, and can have devastating damage if you manage to take out large swathes of their food production. The coalition could even combine them.

The most limiting factor in a suppression campaign would be the size. North America is huge. That means plenty of places to hide bases, manufacturing facilities, defense sites, etc. It would be conceivable that the country could rebuild a sizable force without anyone even being aware of it. There are options for preventing this, but none are going to be foolproof, and they heavily depend on the environmental factors.
Step one, no matter how you wish to go about it, will be getting by their defenses. Air defenses will be the greatest threat to any attempt to subdue this country permanently. With 2000s technology, your best bet is cheap drones. Disposable, controllable, and able to be launched over and over without loss of life.
If the airspace above is toxic as well, manned reconnaissance flights are a no go. You could not patrol it within the time limit. That means drones and satellite monitoring. It could be done, but the odds of something going unnoticed is higher. Any re-building would have to be dealt with immediately and with absolute destruction.
If the airspace itself is not toxic, it would be easier for manned flights to take place. With actual eyes on the ground and the possibility of landing and investigating, the odds of something going unnoticed is lower.
Either situation will require sea or air bases of operation. The patrols cannot move back and forth from one country to another. It would be far more expensive than it is worth. Much better to send your patrols from a central location much closer to the target.
This is all assuming that by "defeat" you mean to ensure that they cannot return and cause trouble again, without complete annihilation. If complete annihilation is on the table, that is also possible without landing a single troop.
With your stated technology era, drones have more than enough firepower to reduce the country to nothing. Constant patrols and air strikes, combined with long range missiles, can do a lot of damage to defenses, population, and infrastructure. Nukes are an option, of course, but run the risk of causing damage to other countries, sea life, etc. Spreading chemicals that will ruin the ecology in that country can also further destabilize the region. Keep up that campaign for long enough and you can easily wipe it out, or at least bring it down to tribal levels of society. Then patrols and surveillance would be enough to manage any consolidations of power and prevent the country from coming back.
Either way, total defeat and destruction is possible using only air superiority. With no outside assistance to the doomed country, they could not continuously defend everything that is important to keeping a country running.

“Defeat” may be possible without war. No matter the power of this alien nation, if every single nation rallied against it, it ought to be outmatched, especially if previously lightly militarized nations kick into high production just for the cause of wrecking this enemy. At this point in time, you reach a point in which the enemy government just quits and surrenders, never to attack again as long as the coalition outmatches it, or the presumably insane leaders are deposed by a population that is being bombed/nuked/starved out of existence. The only thing necessary is a show of force.
